# Dynamically concatenating columns if columns are not null in a single query - for large number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I am trying to create query that concatenates a column header title with its value if the column is not empty e.g.

```
            CREATE TABLE Table1
            ([C1] varchar(50), [C2] varchar(50), [C3] varchar(50),[C4] varchar(50),[C5] varchar(50) )
            ;

            INSERT INTO Table1
            ([C1], [C2], [C3], [C4], [C5])
            VALUES
            ('F92', 'title',null,null,'B350'),
            ('F92', 'title',null,null,'B150'),
            ('F92', 'title',null,null,'PB100')
            ;


            SELECT
              CASE WHEN c3 IS NULL THEN null ELSE c3+c5 END
             FROM table1


            drop table table1
```

this gives the desired result of null. I have over 50 rows and over 30 files (with variable column names) so writing the select query for each column will take way too long and columns may also change in number!

Is this possible to write single query that will look through all columns in a table and returns the result of the following query without having to write it each time for each column

```
            SELECT
              CASE WHEN c1 IS NULL THEN null ELSE 'c1'+c1 END,
              CASE WHEN c2 IS NULL THEN null ELSE 'c2'+c2 END,
             CASE WHEN c3 IS NULL THEN null ELSE 'c3'+c3 END,
             CASE WHEN c4 IS NULL THEN null ELSE 'c4'+c4 END,
             CASE WHEN c5 IS NULL THEN null ELSE 'c5'+c5 END
             FROM table1
```

Comment: take a look at COALESCE instead of case when then else end, it will be shorter

Comment: You don't even need coalesce. Just `'c1' + c1` will be null if c1 is null...

Answer (score 0):

ZLK.. that would still require me manually selecting all columns.. I have files with over 50 columns and not to mention over 30 files .. is there a way to do this dynamically?